# Declaring the same variable name in a JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, variables

All clear with this example (see variable `entry` declaration):

```
var list = { a:1, b:2, c:3 }, entry;

for( var i in list )
{
    entry = list[ i ];

    // ...
}
```

Having 'use strict' no error is thrown, but is it a good practice to declare `entry` this way?

```
var list = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };

for( var i in list )
{
    var entry = list[ i ];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to declare variables at the top, as javascript will interpret them that way regardless: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: it's better to list vars at the top, even if empty at first and repeated later.

Answer (score 3):

Variables declared with `var` are not block-scoped. So your `var entry` inside the loop is available outside the loop as well (i.e., both your declarations are identical). For readability, I like to declare them inside the loop just to make it clear that the variable is only used within the loop (even though I know that it is available outside). If you’re expecting to use `entry` outside the loop, then declare it outside; don’t declare it inside and then end up using it outside (it can be confusing for someone reading your code, even though the code works).

Comment: If you want to declare where its used, why don't you put a comment after it instead of making large jumps and drops in memory with only the result of clarification.

Comment: @WebWanderer AFAIK, variable declarations are hoisted in JS, so what you're describing shouldn't happen.

Comment: They're not hoisted immediately, they kina hang there and wait for the garbage collector to come around and take care of them, and I've tested this numerous times. This will cause a ramp-up in memory, temporarily. If you watch the running browser, you should see a fluctuating memory usage. In this case, because he's only declaring one variable in a short-running loop, the amount would be minute, but imagine how large the consumption could get with a slew of variables in an intensively recursive function/loop. It makes a big difference.

Comment: Its all about the stack and the heap, and yes, you will have "out of stack" errors in JavaScript.

Comment: @WebWanderer You're confusing *declaration* with *assignment*. The variable is declared only once; at the top of the function. Within the stack-frame of the function, you will already have a location assigned for this local variable. Also, your approach wouldn't even solve the problem. Even if you declare `entry` outside, you will keep reassigning it anyway, which means non-referenced values will have to be garbage collected at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared with `var` are not block-scoped, only function-scoped, so the two should be identical.

The variable inside the loop will be “hoisted” to be declared at the function level like in the first example.

The same concept actually applies to the `var i`  as well. It too will be hoisted up to the top of the function.

One micro optimization from the second patterns is that you transfer less code down to the client. This would be more obvious if the names were extra long, though. Not really a practical reason, though.

It is, however, very important to include the `var` keyword. Otherwise, it will become a global property, which is undesirable pretty much all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to iterate through the list, perform some operation and keep the last entry then the first way is clear. If not, you are better off keeping your code clear. There is an a piece of wisdom I heard a long time ago, "Declare your variables right before you use them." There is no reason for strict to complain as you properly declared the variable.

```
if (1) {
    var x = 'hey';
}
console.log(x);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8X2C3/1/ - I didn't realize that JavaScript was function level scoping. That's sad. Don't do things like I put in the example. I see it all the time in PHP and it makes code unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable in JavaScript, you are allocating a substantial amount of memory, how much I am not exactly certain. Yes, JavaScript does not have block-level scoping, and the declaration of that variable should in theory replace the same memory location as your original variable, but it may be making a copy of the memory location before the "garbage collector" comes to take care of it. Declaring a variable in a for-loop could cause a substantial increase in memory and is not a good practice by any means. Yes, the memory will eventually be cleared, but only once the "garbage-collector" gets around to it. I would suggest declaring your variable as you did the first way.

Comment: Variable declarations are hoisted. So you actually don't end up re-declaring the variable over and over again.

Comment: They're not hoisted immediately, but yes, they're hoisted. I put a nice long comment on your post about it. Thanks for down voting. While your at it, how about you study up of the stack and the heap. Also, make some test applications to show which one will run differently and eat more memory. Then, if you still think your right, message me back and show me your code. Ive tested this over and over again.

Comment: I didn't down vote you. Also I already know how the stack and the heap works. :) Can you send me a link to your performance test where you have established this?

Comment: I would love too, but I'm not quite sure how to run this performance test as a fiddle. Hmmm... I have a server, but do I really want to go through the trouble of putting two plain pages out there for debugging purposes? I might. If I do put this test out there somewhere, I'll be sure to post a link to here.

Comment: You can try jsperf.com. I tried out [a simple example](http://jsperf.com/variable-redeclaration/2) and didn't see any appreciable difference.

Comment: Very interesting. I've never seen this cite before either, this is awesome. It did make some difference, yet hardly. I guess there isn't anything substantially wrong about doing this, but I get this uneasy feeling about doing so. I think there's something a little bit more going on, just a little past what we know. I'll be sure to keep checking this out. Sorry for getting a little sour before, I get pretty passionate at times, but I still think that declaring a variable in a loop isn't a good practice unless your absolutely sure what your doing.

Comment: If you find any information on this later on, be sure to post it, this question really struck my curiosity. Thanks @Osvaldas for stretching by brain with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Since variable hosting occurs with the `var` statement, it's usually a better practice (although that is mainly opinion-based) to keep variable declarations at the top of the function.

That might harm readability when you have a lot of local variables, however having many local variables is also an indication that some refactoring could be done such as [Extract Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html).

Also note that the [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) statement will allow block-scoping in ES6.